# Function passed to video.addEventListener("play") event is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am currently working on a React component that requires frames from a video element to be passed onto a canvas element.

While the video is working, the canvas does not draw anything on it. I blieve this is because the method I wrote to draw the frames is not on scope and would appreciate any thoughts on alternative approaches to this as I'm stuck on what to try next.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

class Stream extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.video = React.createRef();
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
    this.screen = React.createRef();

    this.drawFrame = this.drawFrame.bind(this);
  }

  drawFrame(video) {
    const screen = this.screen.current
    screen.height = 500
    screen.width = 500
    let context = screen.getContext('2d')
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, screen.width, screen.height)
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, screen.width, screen.height)
    requestAnimationFrame(this.drawFrame)
    console.log("Screen", screen)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This code runs a video stream.
    const video = this.video.current
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream
        video.play()
        // Says drawFrame is undefined if line below in uncommented.
        //video.addEventListener("play", this.drawFrame(video), false);
        console.log("Video is playing from component")
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occurred! " + err)
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {}

  render() {
    return(
      <Fragment>
          <video
            ref={this.video}
            width="500"
            height="500"
          >Video stream is not available.</video>
          <canvas
            ref={this.screen}
            width="500"
            height="500"
          >Canvas is not available in this browser.</canvas>
          <canvas
            ref={this.canvas}
            width="500"
            height="500"
          >Canvas is not available in this browser.</canvas>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Stream
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost the context for the `this` reference. just use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for a lexical context:

```
.then((stream) => ...
```

If you can't use an arrow function then do it the old way, close over `this` and store it in a different variable then use it instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const _this = this;
    // This code runs a video stream.
    const video = this.video.current
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream
        video.play()
        video.addEventListener("play", _this.drawFrame(video), false);
        console.log("Video is playing from component")
    })
```

Comment: Never thought it would be something like this, I need to review JavaScript rules sometime soon.. I also had to use `this.video.current` when mentioning it on the `drawFrame` function other wise it would throw an error when trying to pass it to `drawImage`.

Thanks very much Sagiv!